# Check if user is member of group

Tags: javascript, groups, user, membership

I have a SharePoint group name "Admin".

Can someone provide me JavaScript code to check if the current logged in user belongs to  this group?

I have a query which I want to run based on this condition.

Comment: Hi Robert,
I could not enter long text which include code in comment box, there is limitation to that

Answer (score 3):

```
function CheckMemberInAdminGroup() {    
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.currentUser = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
    clientContext.load(this.currentUser);

    this.userGroups = this.currentUser.get_groups();
    clientContext.load(this.userGroups);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(success, failure);
}

function success() {
         var groupsEnumerator = this.userGroups.getEnumerator();
          while (groupsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
             var group = groupsEnumerator.get_current();               
             if(group.get_title() == "Admin") {
                 // User is member of Admin group, do stuff
             }
          }
}

function failure() {
          // Something went wrong with the query
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do i need to upload any js file? i yes please provide me the file name also

Comment: What do you mean? You will need to add this JavaScript onto the page, either by pointing to a .js file or adding the JavaScript into a Content Editor Web Part. You don't need any third party libraries, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Just a note, you'll need to use something like ajax createDelegate or jquery $.proxy to pass the "this" object: clientContext.executeQueryAsync($.proxy(this, "success"), $.proxy(this,"failure"));

Answer (score 1):

Check if user is member of group using JSOM:

```
function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {

        var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

        var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
        currentContext.load(currentUser);

        var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
        currentContext.load(allGroups);

        var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);
        currentContext.load(group);

        var groupUsers = group.get_users();
        currentContext.load(groupUsers);

        currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);

        function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
            var userInGroup = false;
            var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
            while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
                if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
                    userInGroup = true;
                    break;
                }
            }  
            OnComplete(userInGroup);
        }

        function OnFailure(sender, args) {
            OnComplete(false);
        }    
}
```

Usage:

```
function IsCurrentUserHasContribPerms() 
{
  IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("Members", function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
    if(isCurrentUserInGroup)
    {
        // The current user is in the [Members] group!
    }
  });

}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(IsCurrentUserHasContribPerms, 'SP.js');
```